# Hibernate L2 cache & entityGraph

Tags: hibernate, caching, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Hibernate 6 with L2 cache and Redis.
I'm trying to avoid useless loadings from database.

I have an entity A that is associated with entity B using ManyToOne. The fetch mode for this association is set to Lazy.

Entity B is stored in the L2 cache with a readonly strategy.

When I request data from the database using a repository (findAll()), and subsequently access entity B through the loaded entity A, I expect entity B to be retrieved from the cache. However, this is not happening; Hibernate is fetching entity B from the database.

If I define an entityGraph to eagerly fetch entity B, Hibernate attempts to join entity B but then tries to store the result in the cache, which is not allowed because entity B is marked as readonly.

Am I having incorrect expectations? How should I proceed to leverage the cache effectively?